# Left windows key doesn't work windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-key

This [image] pops up when I click it.  I have no idea what's blocking it. Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: No; It’s generated by third-party software; does it happen when within safe mode?  You can edit your question

Comment: Agree with Ramhound, it seems some third-party software blocked left windows key. Please check the installed third-party application.

Comment: I agree, but I can't figure out what the heck is doing it.  I was hoping someone would recognize the icon and be able to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went through to figure out what was doing this.  It was iType.exe.